# Regex.Split White Space

Tags: c#

```
string pattern = @"(if)|(\()|(\))|(\,)";
string str = "IF(SUM(IRS5555.IRs001)==IRS5555.IRS001,10,20)";
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(str,pattern,RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) ;
foreach (string match in substrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Token is:{0}", match);
}
```

And out put is

```
Token is:
Token is:IF
Token is:
Token is:(
Token is:SUM
Token is:(
Token is:IRS5555.IRs001
Token is:)
Token is:==IRS5555.IRS001
Token is:,
Token is:10
Token is:,
Token is:20
Token is:)
Token is:
```

As you can see Empty string in 1,3 and last token,i am not able to understand why this kind of result,there is not empty string in my given string.

i don't want this is result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try that :

```
        string pattern = @"(if)|(\()|(\))|(\,)";
        string str = "IF(SUM(IRS5555.IRs001)==IRS5555.IRS001,10,20)";
        var substrings = Regex.Split(str, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Where(n => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(n));
        foreach (string match in substrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Token is:{0}", match);
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This happens because "IF" and "(" are separators and since there is nothing to the left of "IF" and nothing between "IF" and "(" you get these two empty entries. Remove "IF" from the pattern.

```
string pattern = @"(\()|(\))|(\,)";
```

---

UPDATE

You could search for the tokens instead of splitting the string

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"\w+|[().,]|==");
```

This returns exacly the tokens of your text.

```
string[] array = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

```
    [0]: "IF"
    [1]: "("
    [2]: "SUM"
    [3]: "("
    [4]: "IRS5555"
    [5]: "."
    [6]: "IRs001"
    [7]: ")"
    [8]: "=="
    [9]: "IRS5555"
    [10]: "."
    [11]: "IRS001"
    [12]: ","
    [13]: "10"
    [14]: ","
    [15]: "20"
    [16]: ")"
```

---

UPDATE

Another `Regex` pattern you can try together with `Regex.Split` is

```
@"\b"
```

It will split the text at word boundries

```
    [0]: ""
    [1]: "IF"
    [2]: "("
    [3]: "SUM"
    [4]: "("
    [5]: "IRS5555"
    [6]: "."
    [7]: "IRs001"
    [8]: ")=="
    [9]: "IRS5555"
    [10]: "."
    [11]: "IRS001"
    [12]: ","
    [13]: "10"
    [14]: ","
    [15]: "20"
    [16]: ")"
```

Comment: yeah,your are right if i remove if then Empty string remove from 1 and 3 position but still in last position and i don't remove if and continue with same pattern but just remove RegexOptions.IgnoreCase then i got same result as get using your pattern...

Comment: Because it does not recognize "if" if it's case sensitive. You cannot avoid the last empty entry, because ")" is a separator and it separates what's left from it from what’s right from it and because there is nothing on the right you get the last empty entry.